# Convert a many to many raw sql statement to eloquent query builder

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I need to translate this working sql statement:

```
select model_names.name
FROM blog_posts 
INNER JOIN model_names_relations
INNER JOIN model_names
ON blog_posts.id = model_names_relations.blog_post_id and model_names.id = model_names_relations.model_name_id
WHERE blog_posts.id = '12'
```

to laravel query builder. I'm NOT using the full orm, so I can't use the belongstomany feature. I'm restricted to the query builder.

I tried this:

```
$query = ( new DbSql )->db()->table( 'blog_posts' )
        ->join( 'model_names_relations', 'blog_post_id.id', '=', 'model_names_relations.blog_post_id' )
        ->join( 'model_names', 'model_names.id', '=', 'model_names_relations.model_name_id' )
        ->where( 'blog_posts.id', '12')
        ->select( 'model_names.name' )
        ->get();

    var_dump( $query );
    exit;
```

But it won't work I get:

> protected 'message' => string 'SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'blog_post_id.id' in 'on clause' (SQL: select `model_names`.`name` from `blog_posts` inner join `model_names_relations` on `blog_post_id`.`id` = `model_names_relations`.`blog_post_id` inner join `model_names` on `model_names`.`id` = `model_names_relations`.`model_name_id` where `blog_posts`.`id` = 12)' (length=357)
>     private 'string' (Exception) => string '' (length=0)

What would be the correct conversion syntax ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is Laravel query builder

```
$query =DB::table('blog_posts')
->join('model_names_relations', 'blog_posts.id', '=', 'model_names_relations.blog_post_id')
->join('model_names', 'model_names.id', '=', 'model_names_relations.model_name_id')
->where('blog_posts.id', '12')
->get();
```

However your error means there is no 'id' in `blog_post_id` table.

Comment: Thanks, but that is the weird issue: I don't have a blog_post_id table. And the raw sql doesn't cause the issue. blog_post_id is the relation column name.

Comment: Oh ok I got your mistake then. It's a spelling mistake. I fix it for you

Comment: You had a typo on your JOIN. YOu wrote `blog_posts_id.id` instead of `blog_posts.id`. Try again